# Spring boot doesn't serve some of the images from the src/main/resources/public directory

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm trying to develop a small webapp, for learning purpose, with spring boot,thymeleaf and mysql.
I'm using `Eclipse IDE`

Users can upload images to the app, My Controller class store the images in the `src/main/resources/public/images` folder and it's `URL` in the db.
The problem is, Eventhough the images saved by the controller exists in the `src/main/resources/public/images` directory, They are not directly visible in the `public` directory from `Eclipse`, as a result when referred from the served webpages, those images do not show up.
 Some of the images I manually copy pasted into the `public/images` folder within the `Eclipse` .(To do that actually I had to move images to another directory as  it's not possible to copy from and paste into the same folder)

 Those images are rendered in the served web pages..
 The other images saved by the controller, even though they exists in the same directory ,they are not directly visible  from `Eclipse IDE` and they are't rendered in the served pages.

This is `Directory's` view within the eclipse and all these images are rendered correctly in the served webpages

[image]

This is the same directorie's view from the file system, and it contains many images that are not directly visible from eclipse.

[image]

And when I include these images in the webpages , they are'nt rendered even though they reside in the exact same folder as other images..
How to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you run a spring boot or normal spring project using IDE it will bundle everything inside a war and then it serves that bundle so without restarting the server or re-running the application Eclipse doesn't loads the images.

This has nothing to do with spring boot.It is because of the Eclipse IDE as you know if you paste one image inside the folder directory but images wont load without restarting the  server or re-running the application.

My recommendation would be to store images on any directory other than your deployed folder directory and access them without any issues.

I have done this inside tomcat folder without any issue.

Comment: Even after restarting the server it didn'nt work.,Once I refreshed the `public ` folder with in the eclipse , all the images were visible..Is there a way to automatically refresh Eclipse directories when there is a change?

Comment: I didn't find any...so I chose to store inside tomcat directory.

Comment: Doesn't that require an extra controller for these static contents?

Comment: Just one method inside controller which will return byte array image as response

Comment: I got it working by enabling autorefresh of work space on change like this `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace **and check the option **‘Refresh using native hooks or polling`.

Comment: Ok...check by deploying app to server also whether everything works fine.

Comment: so far its working fine, I tested it by uploading profile images and  profile page returned by the server rendered the uploaded image perfectly